# jsonschema.validate() not validating type from schema

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I'm not sure if I'm reading the docs for jsonschema wrong, however from what I can tell, this package should allow me to check that a JSON object conforms to a specified schema using jsonschema.validate(). The following code doesn't tell me that `"age"` should be a number.

```
import json
import jsonschema

schema = '{"name":{"type":"string","required":true},"age":{"type":"number","required":true}}'
schema = json.loads(schema)
data = '{"name":"Foo","age":"Bar"}'

def json_validator(data):
    try:
        json.loads(data)
        print("Valid Json")
        return True
    except ValueError as error:
        print("Invalid JSON: %s" % error)
        return False

def schema_validator(data, schema):
    try:
        jsonschema.validate(data, schema)
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as e:
        print(e)
    except jsonschema.exceptions.SchemaError as e:
        print(e)

json_validator(data)
schema_validator(data, schema)
```

Am I missing something or should this be working?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your schema is not a valid schema. You need to declare these as `properties` and you are using `required` wrong (unless you are on draft-03 which is pretty unlikely at this point). Here's the schema you want.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "age": { "type": "number" }
  },
  "required": ["name", "age"]
}
```